# Access to Azure Files from code through Managed Identity Role Assignment?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-managed-identity, azure-files, azure-storage-files

Is it possible to use a Managed Identity to access an Azure Files container from .Net Core?

A code snippet similar to this. I realize that CloudFileClient does not accept a TokenCredential directly, this is just to show intent. Similar to how I would create a BlobClient.

```
using Azure.Identity;
static void Main(...)
{
    var client = new CloudFileClient(new Uri("..."), new DefaultAzureCredential());
}
```

Can I use a Managed Identity to access Azure Files, or am I relegated to using a legacy secret approach?

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use a Managed Identity to access an Azure Files. You could still construct CloudFileClient with [TokenCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.auth.tokencredential?view=azure-dotnet), see this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-vm-windows-access-storage).

```
TokenCredential token = new TokenCredential("access-token");
StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials(token);

CloudFileClient client = new CloudFileClient(new Uri("..."), credentials);
```

Both `ManagedIdentityCredential` and `DefaultAzureCredential` authenticate the managed identity of an azure resource. Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme#defaultazurecredential) to learn more about DefaultAzureCredential.

[image]

Comment: Hi Pamela, thanks for the reasurance. I've used DefaultAzureCredential for accessing Queues and Blobs, so I understand that well. The example above seemed to address both sides but not connect the two. How do I go from DefaultAzureCredential to TokenCredential? Is it simply a matter of calling GetToken() on an instance of DefaultAzureCredential and passing that string to TokenCredential()?

Comment: The samples above are two methods, you could choose one of them. DefaultAzureCredential is based on your setting, you don't need to get the access token and construct TokenCredential.